# How to convert/parse a string to a date object with Thymeleaf?

Tags: date, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to parse string ISO dates (like "2016-01-01") to be able to format them.
`#dates` and `#temporals` seem to be only able to format Date/LocalDate/LocalDateTime objects.
For instance I want Thymeleaf to display "January 1st, 2016" when it is passed "2016-01-01".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the section [Reformatting dates in our home page](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#reformatting-dates-in-our-home-page) of the reference documentation.

> ....
>
> ...we can do just this:
>
> ```
> WebContext ctx = 
> new WebContext(request, response, servletContext, request.getLocale()); ctx.setVariable("today",
> Calendar.getInstance());
>
> templateEngine.process("home", ctx, response.getWriter());
> ```
>
> …and then perform date formatting in the view layer itself:
>
> ```
> <p>   Today is: <span th:text="${#calendars.format(today,'dd MMMM yyyy')}">13 May 2011</span> </p>
> ```

Comment: Actually I don't want to touch the Java code, I was looking for something I can use exactly the same way as `#temporals`. I ended up coding my own dialect, I'll post an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own dialect containing utility functions such as `parseISODate(String date)` which returns a `LocalDate` then in the HTML I can do

```
th:text="${#temporals.format(#myDialect.parseISODate(someStringISODate), 'dd/MMM/yyyy')}"
```